# How to decrease response time in Nodejs with RDS Postgres

Tags: node.js, mongodb, redis, amazon-rds, httpresponse

My service returns a response of 250ms with 100 users when I increased users' response time increased 600ms to 2sec I want to get a 200ms response with 1000 users or requests per second,
I have deployed my App on AWS-EBS the database which I am using is rds-Postgres
in every request, I am saving every user log to the database

what can I do to decrease my time?
someone said me I should use Redis and save the users' data init and after a 10 records Redis will update the database is this a good option or is there any other option that i can use to achieve my goal

Comment: You can either scale-up or optimise backend.